# How to include generated files for compilation with cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have a set of .xsd files in a subdirectory 'xsd'. I generate a set of .hxx and cxx files for XML-binding with an external command.

```
add_custom_command(
PRE_BUILD
OUTPUT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xsd/file1.hxx ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xsd/file1.cxx
COMMAND ${XSD_EXECUTABLE} cxx-tree
    --file-list-prologue 'set(XSD_GENERATED_FILES '
    --file-list ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_xsd_filelist.txt
    --file-list-epilogue ')'
    --output-dir ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xsd
    ${XSD_SOURCE_FILES}
DEPENDS ${XSD_SOURCE_FILES}
)
```

The tool creates a list of generated files. I have it in the following form:

```
set(XSD_GENERATED_FILES
file1.cpp
file1.hpp
file2.cpp
file2.hpp
)
```

Fine up to here.

Now the part where I don't know how to continue. I want to include the generated file list and add them to the executable.

```
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_xsd_filelist.txt)
add_executable(Prog ${SOURCE_FILES} ${XSD_GENERATED_FILES})
```

But this does not do what I want. Actually, it does nothing because initially `cmake_xsd_filelist.txt` is empty.

My goal is the following:

- when a file in the 'xsd' folder changes, execute XSD_EXECUTABLE for generating the .cpp and hpp files.
- only compile once the generated .cpp files when they have changed
- add the generated source files to the executable.

Is this even possible with cmake? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you know, or can you determine the output files at cmake time?

Comment: No, the file is generated during the build process.

Comment: That's not what I asked :). I'll pretend you told me it's impossible to determine what the generated files will be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Include sources

```
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_xsd_filelist.txt)
add_executable(Prog ${SOURCE_FILES} ${XSD_GENERATED_FILES})
```

This means that you need to have a `cmake_xsd_filelist.txt` file on **configure** step, i.e. xsd must be invoked by [execute_process](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html). Also I think it's better to generate files to binary directory (follow [out-of-source](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees) concept):

```
# Create directory if needed
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated")

execute_process(
    COMMAND
        ${XSD_EXECUTABLE} cxx-tree
        --file-list-prologue 'set(XSD_GENERATED_FILES '
        --file-list "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/cmake_xsd_filelist.txt"
        --file-list-epilogue ')'
        --output-dir "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/xsd"
        ${XSD_SOURCE_FILES}
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
)
```

Do not forget to check successfull exit status:

```
if(NOT result EQUAL 0)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "XSD failed")
endif()
```

Now you can include sources:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/cmake_xsd_filelist.txt)
add_executable(Prog ${SOURCE_FILES} ${XSD_GENERATED_FILES})
```

#### XSD sources update

```
when a file in the 'xsd' folder changes, execute XSD_EXECUTABLE
for generating the .cpp and hpp files.
```

I.e. CMake must run reconfigure if one of the `xsd` file changes. Here is the trick that helps:

```
foreach(x ${XSD_SOURCE_FILES})
  configure_file(${x} ${x} COPYONLY)
endforeach()
```

Now if any of the `XSD_SOURCE_FILES` changes CMake will reconfigure the project effectively re-running `XSD_EXECUTABLE` and re-including `cmake_xsd_filelist.txt`.

Comment: A solution using add_custom_command or add_custom_target would not require re-running cmake or the configure_file trick.

Comment: @steveire In this case you can't include generated list: `include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/cmake_xsd_filelist.txt)`

Comment: Oh, that's an output? Ok.